# Having trouble loggin into website with Jsoup,

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to log into a website with jsoup, I'm pretty sure I am parsing all the things I need to, I just can't figure out what's wrong.

I am using this for reference: http://cs.harding.edu/fmccown/android/Logging-into-Pipeline.pdf

Here is the code that is in my AsycnTask doInBackground:

```
            Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .timeout(10000)
                    .execute();

            Document doc = loginForm.parse();

            //Random values you need to parse to lectio
            String VIEWSTATEXvalue = doc.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATEX").attr("value");
            String EVENTVALIDATIONvalue = doc.select("input[name=__EVENTVALIDATION").attr("value");

            Log.v("MainActivity",VIEWSTATEXvalue + EVENTVALIDATIONvalue);



            doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .data("m$Content$username2", username)
                    .data("m$Content$password2", password)
                    .data("__VIEWSTATEX",VIEWSTATEXvalue)
                    .data("__EVENTVALIDATION",EVENTVALIDATIONvalue)
                    .data("__EVENTTARGET","m$Content$submitbtn2")

                    .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                    .post();
            Log.v("MainActivity", doc.toString());
```

But the problem is it doesn't contain the document of the page when I am logged in, it contains the document for an error page that just says "something went wrong".

I'm guessing this is because I am not parsing all of the parameters.

This is the page I am trying to login to: https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/11/login.aspx?lecafdeling=4733693054

having looked into to some of forms being submitted this was something i could find:

```
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    theForm.submit();
}
}
//]]>
```

But I don't how to parse the proper value for these

Comment: Try setting a timeout. Although I believe is more complicated than that. Inspect the page, in particular check the form tag (action=post) and the submit button. The default behavior is prevented and some javasctipt code is executing. It might be setting more things that you don't know.

Comment: Okay, thanks for getting back to me.  I have to go bed now but I will look into this in the morning, do you mind me reaching out to you if I really can't figure it out?

Comment: Of course not. Just place a comment here.

Comment: okay I tried adding the timeout and changed a few other things, and I'm getting a slightly different error now, a "something went wrong" page. I would really appreciate if you would take a look, of course I will keep trying on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way to see what is being sent by the browser is to inspect the raw http request and just copy the headers. You can do this with Chrome by opening the Development tools by pressing `F12`. Select `Network`. There is a bullet on the upper left. Hover it and it will display `Record Network Log`. This must be red. If it's not press it. This will record all the traffic of the request you will send. You will a number of rows on the table below. Sort by `Method` and select the row with value `POST`(Press on the value of the column `Name`. This is the actual request you are sending. On the panel on the right select `Headers`. Check the `Request Headers` and `Form Data`. Check if all of these values are the same. This will help you in order to hardcode some values that you are missing.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, but i just solved it before the answer. But your comment still helped me!

Comment: Glad that you found the solution. Since my answer was not the solution just post what you did as an answer and accept it, so the thread can be considered closed. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use

```
String EVENTVARGUMENTvalue = doc.select("input[name=__EVENTARGUMENT").attr("value");
```

Comment: Nope it's not. If it was, then jsoup would not be able to parse it. Jsoup is an html parser, it cannot execute javascript, thus it cannot render the dynamic content. In order to see what jsoup will parse, while in chrome press Ctrl+U, this is the actual response from the server, before any javascript executes and generates more content. So, press Ctrl+U and search for this input. You will see that it's there, but it's hidden.

Comment: okay, I just thought the code might be generated by a script or being parsed to the html by javascript. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem. Have fun.